# CheckBox event is not firing

Tags: jquery

I am using a jquery Datatable in which one column is a checkbox. So on selecting it  the change event is not firing.. Here is my code...

```
$("#divAddDocument").on("change", $("input[id*='addDocCheckbox_']"), function (e) {
    var checkboxId = e.target.id;
    var _index = checkboxId.substring(checkboxId.lastIndexOf('_') + 1, checkboxId.length);
    _docUpload.DmsDocumentsList[_index].IsGridItemSelected = true;
    if (_docUpload.IsCorrespondence) {
        $("input[id*='addDocCheckbox_']").each(function () {
            if (checkboxId != $(this).id) {
                $(this).prop("disabled", true);
                $(this).prop("checked", false);
                var _counter = $(this).id.substring($(this).id.lastIndexOf('_') + 1, $(this).id.length);
                _docUpload.DmsDocumentsList[_counter].IsGridItemSelected = false;
            }
        });
    }
});
```

-------------Data table columns-------------------

```
var columns = [
        {
            "data": "", "width": "25%", "name": "Add", "title": "Add", "orderable": false,
            render: function (data, type, row) {
                return '<input type="checkbox" name="Checkbox" class="addDocCheckBox" id="addDocCheckbox_' + row["Counter"] + '">'
            }
        },
        { "data": "DocumentType", "width": "25%", "name": "Document Type", "title": "Document Type", "orderable": false },
        { "data": "IndividualName", "width": "25%", "name": "Name", "title": "Name", "orderable": false },
        { "data": "UploadDateTime", "width": "25%", "name": "Upload Date/Generated", "title": "Upload Date/Generated", "orderable": false }
];
```

Any help is appreciated..

Comment: probably you should use `$(this).attr('id') instead $(this).id`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue is that you need to provide a string as the second argument of `on()` in the delegated event handler, not the jQuery object you currently are. The latter doesn't work because the element does not exist in the DOM when you attempt to select it, hence the jQuery object is empty. Here is a fixed version:

```
$("#divAddDocument").on("change", "input[id*='addDocCheckbox_']", function(e) {
  // your code...
});
```

Another issue is the repeated use of `$(this).id`. `id` is not a property of a jQuery object, hence this will always return `undefined`.

To fix this either use the `id` property of the Element itself:

```
this.id
```

Or use the `prop()` method to get the attribute through jQuery:

```
$(this).prop('id')
```

Here is a fully updated version of your logic:

```js
$('#divAddDocument').on('change', 'input[id*="addDocCheckbox_"]', function(e) {
  var _index = this.id.split('_')[1];
  _docUpload.DmsDocumentsList[_index].IsGridItemSelected = true;

  if (_docUpload.IsCorrespondence) {
    $('input[id*="addDocCheckbox_"]').each(function() {
      if (checkboxId != this.id) {
        this.disabled = true;
        this.checked = false;
        var _counter = this.id.split('_')[1];
        _docUpload.DmsDocumentsList[_counter].IsGridItemSelected = false;
      }
    });
  }
});
```